# Flutter: Gradle failed when trying to built app

Tags: flutter, gradle

Gradle always get stucked for more than 10 minutes when I build

Here are the logs

```
+2671 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[  +98 ms] * What went wrong:
[   +1 ms] Gradle could not start your build.
[   +3 ms] > Could not create service of type ChecksumService using
BuildSessionScopeServices.createChecksumService().
[   +7 ms]    > Cannot lock checksums cache (/home/pavan/new_project/android/.gradle/checksums) as
it has already been locked by this process.
```

Comment: I suggest running the `gradlew clean` & `flutter clean` to clear the possible lock files. Restart the system once, Just in case any process is holding the lock. I have faced this issue only once though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably related to your cache.

If you're using a Windows OS, clear your `.lock` cache in this directory (**search .lock in the directory itself** and remove everything with a **.lock** extension deleted):

**C:\Users<your username>.gradle\caches**

If you got a Linux:
/home/ ***your username*** /.gradle/caches

If you've got a Mac:
/Users/ ***your username*** /.gradle/caches

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10, I deleted all .lock files located in .gradle directory AFTER having restarted my pc !

[image]

[image]